# User Password Not Resetting in ASP Core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Im attempting to create a forgot password feature in asp core with entity framework.

```
 [UnitOfWork]
    public virtual async Task PasswordReset(PasswordResetViewModel resetPasswordViewModel)
    {
        //var user = await GetUserByChecking(emailAddress);

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(resetPasswordViewModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress);

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException("User not found!");
        }

        var result =  await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, resetPasswordViewModel.PasswordResetToken, resetPasswordViewModel.NewPassword);

        switch (result.Succeeded)
        {
            case true:
                throw new UserFriendlyException("Password Reset");
            case false:
                throw new UserFriendlyException(result.Errors.ToString());
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

when the following runs

> userManager.ResetPasswordAsync

i get a successful result however i am still unable to login with the new password and the old password continues to work.

Comment: Not reproduce , could you please show more details/steps to help reproduce ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this. The issue was that I returned an exception on a successful password reset. This for some reason did not save the change . I changed it to return a JSON string and it worked